# What's the difference between readInternal and read in AbstractHttpMessageConverter?

Tags: java, spring

Such as title, I don't understand why there need two method in this class.

[Source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java):

```
/**
 * This implementation simple delegates to {@link #readInternal(Class, HttpInputMessage)}.
 * Future implementations might add some default behavior, however.
 */
@Override
public final T read(Class<? extends T> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage) throws IOException {
    return readInternal(clazz, inputMessage);
}

// ...

/**
 * Abstract template method that reads the actual object. Invoked from {@link #read}.
 * @param clazz the type of object to return
 * @param inputMessage the HTTP input message to read from
 * @return the converted object
 * @throws IOException in case of I/O errors
 * @throws HttpMessageNotReadableException in case of conversion errors
 */
protected abstract T readInternal(Class<? extends T> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException;
```

Comment: 1.) Please do not post images of code but the actual code instead. This makes searching for this e.g. way easier. 2.) It's probably backwards compatibility. The methods might have done something different in the past but do the same thing now (or one was added at a later stage). In order to keep backwards compatability the old method just delegates to the new one so that code can still use it. It's not deprecated though so it might also just be there for convenience.

Comment: I'll pay attention next time, thank you for reminding

Comment: @sibo.wang well, don't remove the images from the question and replace with nothing! As it stands, the question is meaningless. Put everything you need to know into the question, as text.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `read` is `final`. Nobody extending the class can override it.

`readInternal` is `abstract`, so *everybody* extending the class must override it (unless their class is also abstract).

This is superficially unnecessary; but it affords the maintainers of the `AbstractHttpMessageConverter` the chance to change the behavior of all subclasses - for example, calling some method before or after `readInternal` - without passing the burden of invoking before/after to people extending the class.

It's basically future-proofing the design of the class. Or, as [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50173104/whats-the-difference-between-readinternal-and-read-in-abstracthttpmessageconver/50173182#comment87363221_50173104) points out above, it could be the remnant of old code where there used to be something else in the method.